# Global SQLite database in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, global

So I have an `SQLiteDatabase` defined in my `MainActivity` that I populate using some textboxes and a button that confirms the entry. This is the definition:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase clientsDatabase;
    ...
```

And later on, in the `OnCreate` of my `MainActivity` I have this code in a try and catch that sets up the database:

```
clientsDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Clients", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
clientsDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (id INT(3), fName VARCHAR, lName VARCHAR, age INT(3))");
```

I have a function that puts data into the database:

```
clientsDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO clients (id, fName, lName, age) VALUES (" + id + ", '" + f + "', '" + l + "', " + a + ")");
```

And I have a `ListView` that I fill out using the data in this Database. I want to move this `ListView` to another activity. How do I make this database sort of a global thing that can be accessed and edited in any activity in my app? Almost every activity in my app needs interaction with the database, so what options do I have?

Comment: Create a Database class to create the database and another to handle responses. More like a getter and setter of a database.

Comment: read at [Local Databases with SQLiteOpenHelper](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper)

Answer (score 2):

Just add new java class named "DatabaseHandler" and paste below code snippet in your new java file.

```
  public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your database name";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "your table name";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Now if you want this all methods just intialize "DatabaseHandler" in your activity like below.

```
DatabaseHandler DBHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

and for access any method just write like below.

```
DBHepler.addContact(your object);
```